# Redirect everything (pages and subdomains) to new domain page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all pages (including subdomains) of an old domain to a single page on the new domain. All pages will be redirect to the same page on the new domain.

I have countless subdomains on the domain I want to redirect. For this reason I need a dynamic code that redirects all pages, because there is no way for me to find all subdomains.

I have pages like this:

```
old.com
old.com/page1
old.com/page2
sub.old.com
sub2.old.com
sub2.old.com/page
```

I tried all variations of this code but the subdomains won't redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.com/we-moved/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: As a tip, use HTTP 302 (temporary redirect) while testing stuff, and then switch to 301 when you're happy everything works. Browsers cache 301 redirects, making it hard to debug changes. And clearing the cache doesn't help: you may need to use the "forget about this site" option to get all those permanent redirects out of your browser cache.

Comment: awesome idea. what about using the incognito/private browser for this?

Comment: I think incognito mode should work too, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel, Directly use the Redirect Option. IF you want to edit .htaccess file, Checkout my Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clsh\.ga$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.clsh\.ga$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/url\.cloudmate\.in\/" [R=301,L]
```

This htaccess redirects `https://clsh.ga` to new Domain `https://url.cloudmate.in` .

If your htaccess does not redirect then also, try enabling mod_rewrite.c

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new.com/we-moved/? [R=301,L]
```

- `(?:^|\.)old\.com$` will match root domain or any subdomain.
- `?` will discard any query string in redirect.